# Node JS : Conversion from JSON to CSV

Tags: json, node.js, csv

I have a JSON like this,

```
{
    "Name"          : "Gokul",
    "PhoneNumber"   : 9876543210,
    "Qualification" : "BE"
}
```

I need to convert it to CSV and the converted CSV should not have JSON keys, I need to convert only JSON values to CSV and my result should be like this,

```
["Gokul",9876543210,"BE"]
```

Using Node JS, I need to this Conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var json = { "Name" : "Gokul", "PhoneNumber" : 9876543210, "Qualification" : "BE" };
var arr = Object.keys(json).map(function(key,index) {
    return json[key];
});
console.log(arr);
//logs [Gokul,9876543210,BE]
console.log(arr.join(','))
//logs Gokul,9876543210,BE
```

Answer (score 2):

You could install `lodash` (`npm install lodash`) and use [`_.values`](https://lodash.com/docs#values):

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var json = { "Name" : "Gokul", "PhoneNumber" : 9876543210, "Qualification" : "BE" };
var values = _.values(json); // It will be ["Gokul",9876543210,"BE"]
```